# Stop long Fuzzy Finder indexing process

Tags: vim, fuzzy-search

how can we stop or kill a excessive accidental fuzzy indexing?

i have tried

```
kill id & killall id
```

to try kill vim which is chewing up 90 - 100% of the cpu (after getting the top cpu processors with the top command), but indexing continues in vim

Comment: If the process runs inside vim, you can press Ctrl+C. If not, you will have to exclude directories or include specific subdirectories alone.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not an issue tracker so, I generally suggest people to use the plugin's actual issue tracker. But FuzzyFinder's last commit dates back to 2010 and [the issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/ns9tks/vim-fuzzyfinder/issues?status=new&status=open) looks like a ghost town. You should look into another fuzzy gadget or, better, use built-in navigation methods.